# Pass Parameter Or Query String to top nav In _Layout.cshtml In ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

In my controller, I got three parameters. (GET : /Class/List)

```
public class ClassController : Controller {
    public ActionResult List(string classCode = null, string className = null, List<string> semester = null) 
    { ... }
}
```

And I got this in my nav bar...

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Class" asp-action="List">Classes</a>
```

I would like to pass a value of the parameter semester so that the link will look like `localhost/Class/List?semester=9&semester=1`. Thank you!

I have tried ViewBag and asp-route-id but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert List to query string.
action:

```
public IActionResult A()
        {
            ViewBag.List = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
          
            return View();

        }
```

A.cshtml:

```
@{
    var list=ViewBag.List as List<string>;
    var result = "?semester=" +String.Join("&semester=", list);
}
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Class/List@(result)">Classes</a>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might not work because your ActionResult List is expecting a List of Strings. From my experience, a List of strings usually requires you to loop through the Model -> item.semester to list out all the values in your view. 
 
You can try changing `List<string>` to a single `string`.

```
public ActionResult List(string classCode = null, string className = null, string semester = null)
```

Then append this to the "a" tag. Assuming you populate a `Viewbag.semesterId` in your controller.

```
asp-semester="@ViewBag.semesterId"
```